# Linux: blit image on screen without stuttering at a stable frame rate

Tags: c++, c, linux, vsync

I'm working on a very simple game, and one of the project goals is to minimise the use of libraries.

I'm drawing every frame into a buffer, which is then displayed using `XPutImage` (see [the code of the main loop](https://goo.gl/vFE9BK)). This simple code is used to limit FPS:

```
// Limit FPS
{
  u64 current_timestamp = LinuxGetWallClock();
  u64 ns_elapsed = LinuxGetWallClock() - last_timestamp;

  if (ns_elapsed < target_nspf) {
    struct timespec ts;
    ts.tv_sec = 0;
    ts.tv_nsec = target_nspf - ns_elapsed;  // time to sleep
    clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0, &ts, NULL);

    while (ns_elapsed < target_nspf) {
      ns_elapsed = LinuxGetWallClock() - last_timestamp;
    }
  } else {
    // printf("Frame missed\n");
  }

  last_timestamp = LinuxGetWallClock();
}
```

Everything works fine and as expected, but every now and then the image stutters, as if the X server has buffered up a few frames' worth of images and then flushed them all in a single go. This happens irrespective of frame misses.

Note: I'm not talking about image tearing here.

I realise that the code above is not supposed to provide a stable frame rate, and occasionally one frame might be displayed for too long, and another frame might get lost and never displayed, but I don't see how that thing alone can cause the terrible occasional stuttering.

My only guess would be that `clock_nanosleep` may sleep for longer than I asked for.

### Questions:

- Is my guess above correct?
- If not, what might be the reason?
- Are there any ways to address this problem without having to use OpenGL to wait on vblank?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi there. I'm pretty sure this isn't a solution to your issue, but have you tried using `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` in your `clock_gettime()` call? If you look at the manpage for `clock_gettime()`, it states the following for `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`:

`Similar to CLOCK_MONOTONIC, but provides access to a raw hardware-based time that is not subject to NTP adjustments or the incremental adjustments performed by adjtime(3).`

So it could cause slight issues with your times, but it's probably very unlikely. But it would be nice to try in order to rule that out.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. Just tried that, it didn't help, as you expected